# Qt/C++ get Xid of all application windows

Tags: c++, qt

I'm using gstreamer with Qt/C++ and I'd like to use "ximagsrc xid=[MyXid]", replacing [MyXid] by the Xid of every windows on my computer.
I found the following command line :

```
wmctrl -l
0x02a00002  0 Fry XdndCollectionWindowImp
0x02a00005  0 Fry unity-launcher
0x02a00008  0 Fry unity-panel
0x02a0000b  0 Fry unity-dash
0x02a0000c  0 Fry Hud
0x02c0000a  0 Fry Desktop
...
```

to get the IDs. (I'am able then to use "ximagsrc xid=0x02a00002" for example)

But I'm programming in Qt/C++ and

I'd like to get these values automatically. I could launch this command line through C++ but if "wmctrl" isn't installed on the computer, my program wouldn't work. (it also seems to be a bad way for me, isn't it ?)

Is there any way to do this with C++ or Qt ?

Thank you,

Have a nice day !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `wmctrl`, you could also use `xwininfo`, which may be more readily available.

If you want to implement this functionality in your program, you can use xlib or xcb to implement a client that retrieves this information from the X server. Check the source code of `wmctrl` or `xwininfo` to see how they do it.

Comment: Thank you, I am looking the source code of wmctrl. Fortunately, it's C code so I can add It to my Project ! I guess it is the same thing for xwininfo. I don't know why one is better than the other but I like the way that wmctrl displays the informations.

Comment: The recommendation to use xwininfo was made because it is typically part of a standard Xorg installation, so it is more likely to be installed than wmctrl.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [xwininfo](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xwininfo): `xwininfo -root -children`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for you answers.

I finally took the source code of wmctrl and changed it to get what I needed I guess it can work with windows. Unfortunately, it doesn't work for Mac but anyway gstreamer for Mac recording screen is still a bad plugin unable to do this.